# Queueing task by using ExecutorService or by using my own queue

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

We have an API endpoint that is called very rapidly

Each call has a payload that needs to be handled offline

We have 2 options:

1. For each API call, submit a new task using ExecutorService. The tasks will pile up in the internal queue of the ExecutorService (we can ignore memory problems for now).
2. For each API call, add the payload to some queue and return immediately

   Have some X amount of threads that will pull items from that queue and handle them

Is there a difference between these 2 approaches? what could be better?

Is the first approach consuming more memory than the second one per each work item?

Comment: The first approach is basically an abstracted version of the second approach. The first is better, because you don't have to implement the queueing/threads bit of it.

Comment: Re, "Is the first approach consuming more memory...?" They'll probably be about the same unless there is some difference between what you call a "task" in the first case and an "item" in the second case. There's no reason why there _should_ be a difference, because both describe the same piece of work that needs to be done by the worker threads.

Comment: Does the collection of incoming payloads need to be durable? For example, if there are 10,000 pending items and the system goes down, is it ok to lose those 10,000 items? What's an upper limit of incoming payloads – 10k, 100k, 1M, 10M, etc?